c++17 User-defined literals strange behavior for sequence of strings
I spent some time while diagnosting the bug where I lost the comma between two strings created with std::string_literals.
EDIT
As soon a lot of commenters address to really clear case of compiler like "one" "two" that is single string, I need to emphasise using of user literal for this purpose I've added 2 extra operators: _kylobyte and my_ns::s (I know it is bad not to use '_').
EDIT 2
Okay, @user17732522 argues to fundamental lex behaviour. So I bring one more user-defined-string-literal boom. Compiler behavior that it collects together similar user defined but works as expected when 2 different is in use. So not only lex should be taken to account.
Minimal reproducible code is following:
#include <iostream>

template <class ...Tx>
void consume_all(Tx&&  ...tx)
{
    ((std::cout << tx),...);
}
namespace my_ns
{
    inline std::string operator "" s( const char* str, size_t n)
    {
        return std::string{str, n} + "+";
    }
    inline std::string operator "" _boom( const char* str, size_t n)
    {
        return std::string{str, n} + "*";
    }
}
inline  std::string operator "" _kylobyte( unsigned long long int c)
{
    return std::to_string(c*1000);
}
int main()
{
    using namespace my_ns; //PAY attention not std::string_literals;
    consume_all(
        "abc"s // comma is missed there
        "123"s
        , //without this boom fails
        "123"_boom
        "abc"_boom  //still doesn't need comma
        , // compiler needs this
        12_kylobyte
    );
}

Code is compiled without any errors on MSVC 2022 and Clang 6.0. So my question: what the part of the specification describes this behavior?

In C++ all adjacent literal strings are concatenated into a single string. It happens in phase 6 of translation.

Yep.  It's always been true, clear back to the original implementation of C.  "one" " " "two" " " "three" is equal to "one two three".

"Coma" is a medical tern, you meant "comma", a grammar term.

@Someprogrammerdude I cannot agree that it is so simple, just tried this: inline  std::string operator "" _kylobyte( unsigned long long int c) ... without comma. Compilation has been failed.

@TimRoberts Sure I know about "one" "two", but pay attention to using operator "". What if operator "" ... brings some logic (even with respect to constexpr)

@Dewfy _kylobyte is not a user-defined literal string operator. Not sure why that is relevant to the question.

"what the part of the specification" -- This implies that a reference to cppreference.com would be inadequate, so [tag:language-lawyer] seems appropriate.

Now this question is marked as "duplicate", but I don't think this question is duplicate. In the ISO C++ standard the chapter lex.ext#8 defines a rule specifically for user-defined literals: "At the end of phase 6, if a string literal is the result of a concatenation involving at least one user-defined-string-literal, all the participating user-defined-string-literals shall have the same ud-suffix and that suffix is applied to the result of the concatenation". This rule describes the behavior of this question.

@user17732522 please see my edit to address your doubt kylobyte is not a user-defined literal string operator. (just realized may be you miss that s is library defined operator, not by compiler)

@Dewfy I didn't miss anything. s is a user-defined string literal operator and _kylobyte is a user-defined literal operator, but not a user-defined string literal operator. The concatenation rule applies to string literals (including those with user-defined literal suffix), but not to any other form of literals. "abc"s and "123"s are user-defined-string-literals (which for the purpose of concatenation is a string-literal), but 12_kylobyte is a user-defined-integer-literal.

I have reopened the question because it now clearly differentiates from the basic string literal concatenation question.

As a side note, the declaration inline std::string operator "" s( const char* str, size_t n) is not permitted. The user is only allowed to define  literal operators starting with _. All other names are reserved for the standard library.

@user17732522 thank you for comment, but I've put disclaimer (I know it is bad not to use '_').  as soon Clang renders the warning ([-Wuser-defined-literals])

@JaMiT please see my edit with adding _boom _boom operators

@JaMiT - the question never mentioned sv operator. The question about standart way to override operators. If my implementation of operator"" makes some extra logic (like my_ns::operator "" adds '+' I'm curious if it can be used in cross-platform way. That is why I'm asking about point in the spec.

This is not specific to user-defined string literals.
You can (and always could, already in C) concatenate multiple string literals by writing them directly after one another, possibly separated by whitespace.
The user-defined literal suffixes must not conflict (i.e. there must not be two different ones) but otherwise it works with user-defined literals the same way. (See [lex.string]/8 together with [lex.ext]/8.)
        "abc"s // comma is missed there
        "123"s

is exactly equivalent to
        "abc123"s

The concatenation is done after preprocessing directives are executed, but before preprocessing tokens are converted into tokens and any other analysis of the source code happens, in particular before the string literal is rewritten into a call to the user-defined string literal operator. See translation phase 6 in [lex.phases]/1.6

12_kylobyte is not a (user-defined) string literal and there is therefore no concatenation rule that would apply to it. If you leave out the comma between "123"s and 12_kylobyte, then you would attempt to parse one literal followed by another in an expression, which the expression grammar does not permit.

I cannot agree with your answer, what if operator ""s brings some logic (even with respect to constexpr declaration)

@Dewfy The compilation process happens exactly as I described. It doesn't matter what the literal operator does. It will be called exactly once as if in "abc123"s. If that is not the desired behavior, then one shouldn't write it like that.

Your edit and referencing to lex behaviour makes more sense. But now I'm presenting new user defined string literal boom please see the edit and consequences

@Dewfy "The user-defined literal suffixes must not conflict (i.e. there must not be two different ones)"

Super! That's what I'm asking about - just point me please!

You may disagree with the choice of the designers, but you cannot disagree with his answer.  Those are facts.  First, the strings are concatenated.  Then, the user-defined operator is applied.

@TimRoberts I never demonstrated disagreement, my question was to point me on specification part. Reference to lex implementation only partial answer because may vary from compiler to compiler. My example with "a"s "b"_boom demonstrates that lex at least should recognize that applied operators are different. Can I relly that cross-platform code provides same semantic?

@Dewfy All of my statements in the answer are in relation to what the standard requires, not about implementation-specific behavior. I would state that explicitly otherwise. I linked to the normative wording in the standard draft. The last part you are asking about specifically has equivalent normative wording in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/lex.ext#8.sentence-3.

The answer is clear and comprehensible. @Dewfy, I would gladly accept it, if it was my question.

Short version
Adjacent literals that are enclosed by double quotes (") are concatenated, any suffix from any piece is kept, then the relevant operator is invoked.
Full version
Adjacent string literals are concatenated. Other kinds of literals are not concatenated. This holds even when one or more suffixes are present ([lex.ext]/8). In this context, "string" refers to what appears in the source code, not the result of applying the suffix. That is, ""_as_int is a string literal, even if the _as_int turns it into an integer, and 1_stringify is an integer literal, even if the _stringify turns it into a string.
The interesting part happens when adjacent string literals do not all have the same suffix. Each suffix applies to all concatenated string literals; if this produces a conflict, the code is ill-formed ([lex.ext]/9). This is similar to how prefixes have been handled since C++11. This means that when you intentionally split a string literal into adjacent pieces, you do not have to copy the suffix to each piece. (The prefix might be needed on each piece, depending on the content.)
Syntactically, it does not matter if a suffix is defined by the user or provided by the standard library (something in the std namespace). What would matter is if a suffix was defined by the core language syntax, such as 1LL for integer literals. (In this respect, "non-core" might be more understandable than "user-defined".) However, the language syntax defines no such suffix for string literals, so any string literal with a suffix falls under the "user-defined literals" category (covered by [lex.ext]). In particular, there was no need for the question to complicate its example code with custom suffixes, especially not another s, which shows a disregard for robust, cross-platform code, as that literal suffix identifier is reserved by [usrlit.suffix].
NOTE: The following table assumes using std::literals is in effect to get the standard string (s) and string view (sv) suffixes.



Adjacent string literals
Equivalent to




"A"  "BC"
"ABC"


"A"s "BC"
"ABC"s


"A"  "BC"s
"ABC"s


"A"s "BC"s
"ABC"s


"A"s "BC"sv
ERROR



Demonstration
While a custom suffix is not necessary for demonstrating the syntax rules, it can be useful for concisely demonstrating the concatenation in action. The below code defines a suffix with some diagnostic output that allows us to see what the compiler sees.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::size_t operator ""_size(const char* str, std::size_t size) {
    std::clog << "Invoked: \"" << str << "\"_size\n";
    return size;
}

int main()
{
    [[maybe_unused]] auto v1 = "A"_size "BC";
    [[maybe_unused]] auto v2 = "A"      "BC"_size;
    [[maybe_unused]] auto v3 = "A"_size "BC"_size;

    using namespace std::literals;
    // [[maybe_unused]] auto v4 = "A"_size "BC"s;
    //                                     ^~~~~
    // error: inconsistent user-defined literal suffixes '_size' and 's' in string literal
}

Output
Invoked: "ABC"_size
Invoked: "ABC"_size
Invoked: "ABC"_size

Adjacent string literals are concatenated, the suffix applied to the result, then the relevant operator is invoked.
